# Как заполнить пустые строки в датафрейме

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Имеется список списков, представляющих собой датафрейм:

```
[['', '', '', 'г. Москва', '27972,5'],
 ['Центральный', '22103,9', '100,2', 'Орловская область', '17229,8'],
 ['', '', '', 'Мурманская область', '23320,8'],
 ['Северо-Западный', '21029,5', '100,0', 'Новгородская область', '17881,9'],
 ['', '', '', 'Краснодарский край', '20517,5'],
 ['Южный', '19085,2', '100,0', 'Республика Адыгея', '17788,5']]
```

Как заполнить пропуски значениями из следующих строк, чтобы получить датафрейм следующего вида:

```
[['Центральный', '22103,9', '100,2', 'г. Москва', '27972,5'],
 ['Центральный', '22103,9', '100,2', 'Орловская область', '17229,8'],
 ['Северо-Западный', '21029,5', '100,0', 'Мурманская область', '23320,8'],
 ['Северо-Западный', '21029,5', '100,0', 'Новгородская область', '17881,9'],
 ['Южный', '19085,2', '100,0', 'Краснодарский край', '20517,5'],
 ['Южный', '19085,2', '100,0', 'Республика Адыгея', '17788,5']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените сначала пустые строки на nan, а потом bfill все прекрасно заполнит

```
df.replace('', np.nan).bfill()
```